# Salesforce :Is it possible to simplify the below 2 SOQL queries to 1 SOQL

Tags: salesforce

I need to merge the 2 SOQL in the below code to one ,is it possible ?

**Requirement :-**
When Opportunity is inserted, Check the Account is having private flag checked, if yes then check if the account is in the logged in users territory. If yes allow the creation of Opportunity else show an error message.
Execute the above functionality only when size of trigger context is 1.

**Code :**
**Trigger :**

```
\\Only for one record Insertion
if (Trigger.new.size()==1) 
{
    \\Get all Accounts which are marked private(Confidential)
    Account acc = [select id, Confidential_Account__c 
                   from Account 
                   where id= :Trigger.new[0].AccountId];
    if (acc.Confidential_Account__c==true)
    {
        OpportunityTriggerUtil
        .checkIfAccountExistInUserTerritory(Trigger.new[0], 
                                            Trigger.new[0].AccountID, 
                                            userInfo.getUserID());
    }
}
```

**Class:**

```
public static void checkIfAccountExistInUserTerritory(Opportunity opp,ID AccountID,ID currentuserid)
{
    Boolean isAccountInTerritory=false;

    \\Get all Sales territory Account for logged in user
    for(Sales_Territory_Account_Assignment__c SA: 
        [select id, Account__c 
        from Sales_Territory_Account_Assignment__c 
        where Sales_Territory__c in 
            (select Sales_Territory__c 
            from Sales_Territory_User_Assignment__c 
            where user__c = :currentuserid)])
    {
        \\Check whether the Account is in Logged in user territory
        if(SA.Account__c==AccountID)
        {
            isAccountInTerritory = true;
        }
    }
    system.debug('@@@@@  '+ isAccountInTerritory);
    if(isAccountInTerritory == false)
    {
        opp.addError('Selected account is not in your territory');
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems - performance (your code is not "bulk") and logical (only 1st opportunity is checked - which will be fine for edits that happen from web interface but might not work the way you'd like it to work when tools like Data Loader are used). From a look at the code you've provided I'd say that it might hit the limit of 50K returned rows, not the 101 queries limit. So there must be some bigger flow outside that causes multiple entries to that trigger - and if you haven't posted the whole context, what kind of magic you expect?

Typically such questions should be followed up with comment along the lines of "what have you done to actually try fixing the problem" but I suspect if you've written this originally you have still a lot to learn...

Welcome to StackOverflow but next time please spend some time reading the right-side links in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask?

And please - none of this "Please provide a solution ASAP."...

---

If I read it correctly your database model looks like that:

[image]

*(created in https://www.draw.io/)*

Something like this should give you enough ideas to get started:

```
SELECT Id, Account__c
FROM Sales_Territory_Account_Assignment__c
WHERE Account__c = :AccountID
    AND Sales_Territory__r.User__c = :currentuserid
```

You still have LOTS of improvement opportunities here:

- start checking more than 1 Opp at a time
- but figure out which Accounts are to be checked and don't re-check them (if there are 10 opps modified at the same time but they belong to only 2 accounts - make only 2 checks)
- maybe add `LIMIT 1` - just in case there are multiple entries - you're fine with just knowing there exists at least 1 match try combining this all in 1 giant query that goes through Account (to fetch info about this confidential flag) and related list of assigned territories in one go.
- check it only once in whole transaction (there might be multiple entries to same trigger if your logic is complex and updates Opportunity several times).

In fact **this last bit might be most important to you  if you have problem with 101 queries**. You'll need a trick like static variable flag to [not execute same piece of code more than once](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005328&language=en_US).

---

More reading material:

1. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm
2. http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/04/20/writing-bulk-triggers-for-salesforce/
3. http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/controlling-recursive-triggers
4. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16322/trigger-isexecuting-clarification
5. http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/controlling-recursive-triggers

Comment: Thanks for the Information.
We are using this for only one record ,
Only when one opportunity is inserted via UI and one Opportunity is inserted thro Dta Loader ,

Comment: Thanks for the Information.
We are using this for only one record ,
Only when one opportunity is inserted via UI and one Opportunity is inserted thro Dta Loader ,
Since its only for one record ,thats the reason code is not Bulkified.

Data Model is correct,
I am trying to Simplyfy the soql in to one , As we dont need 2 Soql
So that we dont Hit limits Now & in Future releases,
I am doing this for only 1 record , we are not doing for Update only for Insert.
Thanks for your suggestion , will Implement .

Comment: Thanks for the Information. We are using this for only one record , Only when one opportunity is inserted via UI and one Opportunity is inserted thro Dta Loader , Since its only for one record ,thats the reason code is not Bulkified. Data Model is correct, I am trying to Simplyfy the soql in to one , As we dont need 2 Soql So that we dont Hit limits Now & in Future releases, I am doing this for only 1 record , we are not doing for Update only for Insert. Thanks for your suggestion , will Implement

Comment: The wy it's written it'll waste at most 2 queries (1 in trigger, 1 in class). If you're hitting "101 queries" it means it's part of bigger process that enters here multiple times? Are you using stuff like `Trigger.isInsert()` to really enforce it's not run during updates for example?

Comment: HI @eyescream ,
We are using this piece of code in Opportunity Before insert Trigger ,Which is a Big process,
We are actually Restricting User not to create Opportunity who are not in the sales territory,
This is used only in User Interface ,so when a user creates an opportunity & he is not part of sales territory he will get the error message.
As of now many of them are working on the Before Insert trigger, we are trying to minimize the Soqls,So that we dont cross the limit in Future releases.

Thanks

Comment: I am getting (Too many query rows: 50001)
I am using the same code which i posted in the beginning of the Question,
We will be using 2 queries & i am getting the 50k error for few users

Kindly let me know how to go about it

I am using the Below code now:


Thanks & Regards
Prakash